# Extract numbers and decimal from string in EXCEL

Tags: excel, feature-extraction, text-extraction

I have an Excel file that contains roughly 40,000 rows of data and i am trying to create a new columnn of only the number and decimal portion of a strinng in another column. I tried to TRIM() and LEFT() but the number value size effects that extraction.  I also saw another post in StOv that extracts numbers only but my goal is to grab the decimals so I can see the exact value.  Here is an example of the content of one cell.  Thanks for any help!!!

```
ABCD-EF (-320.94) GHI HOUSEHOLD COLLECT AGENCY
```

My desired outcome would be:
`320.94` or `-320.94`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, Gary....worked great.  Doesnt seem to find the 0.00 values but i can work with those misses.  Thanks again!!!@

Comment: @user2822055  Do you want **hsadkguegz()ncckasjcsj** to report **0.0**??